# How to map custom key combinations on Wacom Bamboo MTE-450A

Tags: 16.04, wacom, graphics-tablet, remapping, bamboo

I'm trying to use my Wacom tablet in Ubuntu 16.04, and the mapping is quite limited compared to the Windows drivers. I tried to use the terminal, but found it too complicated.

So how do I set custom keys? And why is Ubuntu not detecting the buttons on my tablet, only the pen?

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you found using the terminal too complicated, but I just wanted to make sure you saw the xsetwacom and Wacom consumer tablet ExpressKey instructions at http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Consumer_Tablet_ExpressKey_Mapping_Issue

You want to do something like:

```
xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo Pad pad" Button 1 "key esc"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo Pad pad" Button 3 "key F11"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo Pad pad" Button 8 "key ctrl alt t"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo Pad pad" Button 9 "key p"
```

after running xsetwacom --list to get the name of the device in the first set of quotes.

The button numbers (1,3,8,9) will most likely be out of order.